# TSQL - Find the minimum in the range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Edit:
Problem Statement:
Select all SIIIS and SULLS data between start of Mar and end of May

For each “XFFF” in SIIIS look for any matches in “XFFF” in SULLS where “Start_Time” in SULLS is after “Case_Create” in SIIIS and the time difference between “Start_Time” and “Case_Create” is less than 3 hours. 
Select the match with the smallest time difference

```
select 
si.XFFF xfff,     
DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) diffInhours
from siiis si inner join sulls su on si.xfff= su.xfff
where
 ((si.CASE_CREATE BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130531') and (su.START_TIME between '20130301'AND '20130531'))
 and 
 (su.START_TIME > si.CASE_CREATE) and 
 (DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) < 3 and DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) > 0)
```

Comment: better.. if you also include your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to clean up and fix your code, should runs on sqlserver 2008+, datediff will not give you the difference in hours(very common misunderstanding), so I took a different approach:

```
select 
si.num_phone Phone, 
su.start_time sulstarrtTime ,
si.CASE_CREATE siStartTime,
datediff(hour, 0, su.START_TIME - si.CASE_CREATE)  diffInhours
from siiis si 
cross apply
(select top 1 * from sulls su
 where
 si.xfff= su.xfff
 and su.START_TIME > si.CASE_CREATE
 -- less than 3 hours difference
 and dateadd(hour, 3, si.CASE_CREATE) > su.START_TIME
 -- more than 1 hour difference your code indicated you needed this, your text said otherwise
 --and dateadd(hour, 1, si.CASE_CREATE) <= su.START_TIME
 order by START_TIME
) su
WHERE si.CASE_CREATE BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130531' -- you are not including all of may
```

Comment: Looks like your solution works, you are a champ. But I did not understand your code :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code . Basically what it is supposed to do is that it orders on `DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME)` in ascending order and then picks the first 1.It is not tested so I explained the logic.

```
SELECT TOP 1
si.num_phone Phone,
su.start_time sulstarrtTime ,
si.CASE_CREATE siStartTime,
DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) diffInhours
from siiis si inner join sulls su on si.num_phone = su.num_phone
where
((si.CASE_CREATE BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130531') and (su.START_TIME between '20130301'AND '20130531'))
and 
(su.START_TIME > si.CASE_CREATE) and 
(DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) < 3 and DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) > 0) 
order by DATEDIFF(hour, si.CASE_CREATE, su.START_TIME) ASC
```

Comment: It gets me exactly one record. But I need one record when there are multiple records.

Comment: you mean you want to show all the records with minimum difference ?